# press button and value increases in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

So when the page loads the text box will contain a stored value. I want the user to press the '+' button and the value in the text box will increase by one. Im guessing this is done with JQuery...Any ideas on where to get started so far I have...

```
<input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" id="BoqTextBox" value="0" />  
    <input type="Button" value="+" onclick="AddOne(document.getElementById('BoqTextBox').value)" />

    <script>
        function Add(data) {
            //so the current digit is passed to here, where I need to do some funky code
            //where it increments the current digit by one and stores it in BoqTextBox - replacing the old digit.

            //Also to note if the text box contains 124.54 for example and + is pressed
            //then new value will be 125.54
        }
    </script>
```

Any assistance with this would be great.

Thank you

...something like data = data + 1, but then how do I return the value into the text box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to fetch and set a value.  In this case the code you need could look like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/swQkS/1/)):

```
<input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" id="BoqTextBox" value="0" />
<input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" />
<script>
$('#AddButton').on('click', function () {
    var input = $('#BoqTextBox');
    input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) + 1);
})
</script>
```

Comment: function called is AddOne and your function is Add.. do you really think this will work ???

Comment: Yeah I had caught that when trying to set up a JSFiddle.  Should be fixed :)

Comment: @JasonSperske Only problem with this is that if I set the value in the text box to a decimal no. 1.14

and press the + button the value jumps to 2. I need it to change to 2.14

thanks for the reply. any ideas on this one?

Comment: You could replace `parseInt` with `parseFloat`

Comment: @Mick, just a head up there is more to dealing with `parseFloat()` than meets the eye: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578841/why-does-parsefloat-in-javascript-produce-consisant-but-unitinutive-results

Comment: [`parseFloat()` does not accept a radix parameter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: Opps, I had `parseInt()` in my first draft, and changed it too quickly

Comment: @JasonSperske that's great man thanks for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {  // bind click event to button
   $('#BoqTextBox').val(function() {      // change input value using callback
      return ++parseFloat( this.value, 10); // make value integer and increment 1
   })
});
```

Comment: I like that `++parseInt()` approach

Answer (score 1):

you are callin Addone function inline so that means your function should be AddOne()

try this

```
function AddOne(obj){
    var value=parseFloat(obj) + 1;
    $('#BoqTextBox').val(value);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#buttonId").click(function()
 {        
    var txtBox = $("#boqtextbox"); 

    if(!isNaN(txtBox.val()))
    {
       txtBox.val(parsFloat(txtBox.val())+1) ;

    }else 
    {
       //do validation or set it to 0
       txtBox.val(0);
    }|

 });
```