# Increase counter value upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to get the jQuery bit I need to work. I've never used jQuery before, but I'd like to have a button on my page that, when clicked, increments an initially 0 value by one. My question is similar to [jQuery - Increase the value of a counter when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701349/jquery-increase-the-value-of-a-counter-when-a-button-is-clicked) and [press button and value increases in text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576769/press-button-and-value-increases-in-text-box) but I can't make sense of what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#update").click(function()
{
    $("#counter")++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="TextBox" id="TextBox" value="0" />
<input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#AddButton').on('click', function ()
{
    var input = $('#TextBox');
    input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 1);
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please forgive any huge glaring mistakes, I have no idea how to do any of this yet. Thank you, and happy tidings! =)

Comment: where are the elements `update` and `counter`? and why do you have jquery two times included?

Comment: `$("#counter")` returns a handle to the (wrapped) DOM element whose Id is "counter". That element may have a numeric property that could be incremented, but the element itself is not a number, and so you cannot increment it.

Comment: Why downvote  ? Ok, there are mistakes but honestly the Q&A format is respected, there's code... We can help **guide** people to understand and better themselves, after all isn't this what STO is all about ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's clear you're new to jQuery, so a good read might be of help to you, I would recommand **Head First jQuery**.

As for the question, I rewrote your code, here's what it should be like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My first increment </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" name="TextBox" id="TextBox" value="0" />
        <input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#AddButton').click( function() {
                    var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
                    counter++ ;
                    $('#TextBox').val(counter);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a little test : [test me](http://jsfiddle.net/hsAsU/2/)

The idea is to increment a variable not an object, and you have some syntax mistakes as well, but try this code and we can discuss it further on comments.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! :D I'll check up on Head First jQuery. Is there a way to make the value persistent for all users who see the page? Would I have to connect it to a database somehow?

Comment: Yeah, I think as soon as you close the page (a view), the counter value will be lost unless you stock it in a DB. To connect to DB with jQuery you'll have to go with ajax :)

Answer (score 2):

(This is merely a supplement to other answers)

You only need to load this once ***before*** all other js `src`s:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

That's a really old jquery version.  You can find the latest [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery).

Almost all jQuery code should be wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Do it all of the time until you find a reason not to which is rare for pure jQuery.

Assuming `$('#TextBox')` can never be changed from the last counter, you might like:

```
$('#TextBox').val(0);
$('#AddButton').click( function() {
    $('#TextBox').val(parseInt($('#TextBox').val()) + 1);
});
```

but if you want `TextBox` to be changed by the user then set back to the incrememented counter whenever `AddButton`'s clicked, assuming `counter` should start at `0`:

```
counter = 0;
$('#AddButton').click( function() {
    counter++;
    $('#TextBox').val(counter);
});
```

Comment: `this` will refer to `#AddButton`, will it not ?

Comment: @Gloserio i hate `this`.  was just trying to be cool.  will change for 100% surety.  but still pretty sure it changed to `TextBox` since i do it for `type=check`s all the time.

Comment: Haha, sorry man, but I was kind of asking the question because I was dubious and wanted some confirmation. `this` inside an event will point to the component firing it ( unless I am mistaken ). Otherwise I tried `$('#TextBox').val($('#TextBox').val()++);` on jsFiddle but it doesn't work, why is that in your opinion ?

Comment: @Gloserio thought i could get away with not using `parseInt`.  guess not.  ditching the increment too.  edit number 3...

Comment: Actually, you could, but it's not about that, its the `++` following the `$('#TextBox').val()` statement, it doesn't like it for some reason... Here try this http://jsfiddle.net/hsAsU/3/ , uncomment one piece of code at time and notice the difference.

Comment: Hihi...now its working just fine and you got it all in one line (programmers poetry, sort of...). Otherwise good explainatory answer, now I can +1 you since you got it all together :p !

Comment: @Gloserio that's so weird that `++` can't be done inline.  is that the only function that can't be?  lol.  +1 for you sticking up for beginner.  i remember those days...

Comment: Yeah, that's actually weird the `++` doesn't work.. If I find out why I'll let you know. (hard days indeed...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641480/inline-in-jquery-not-working/17641595?noredirect=1#17641595 , check this out ! Actually, we kind of were quite the blind ones lool...

Comment: @Gloserio oh, it's on now!  ;))  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3469896/1382306  i tried to preincrement, but that didn't work.  guess `$.val()` can't be incremented.  think it's in the chk n ur link

Comment: Well, preincrement or postincrement will equally not work @Gracchus. It's simply that `parseInt($('#TextBox').val())` is a value, and you can't increment a value, you can only increment a variable (of which a value will be incremented). We missed that :D but now we know ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var counter = 0;
$("#update").click(function()
{
    counter++;
});
```

Demo for this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hsAsU/)**.

If counter is a variable you need to define it (`var counter;`) and you forgot also to close the click ")". Notice the extra `)` in the end. What you were doing was increment a jQuery object (good idea to explain Ohgodwhy).

In case what you want is to put the value in another field (and now I am guessing a bit), like an input field, you can do this:

```
var val;
$("#update").click(function()
{
   val = $('#counter').val();
   val++;
   $('#counter').prop('value',val )
});
```

Demo for this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/wMUTg/)**.

Comment: And the reason for this is that you can't increment a jQuery object, which is what OP was doing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using plain html and JS, Attaching the code below

```
<b>
<button id="btn" onclick="this.innerHTML=++this.value" value=0 >0</button>
</b>
```