# Inline `++` in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Astonished to find out that a line like this :

```
$('#TextBox').val(parseInt($('#TextBox').val())++ );
```

Will not work !

I've done some tests, it plays out to the conclusion that the inline `++` doesn't work (in Javascript as a whole ? Or simply in my example ?).

Here's a [test with three pieces of code](http://jsfiddle.net/hsAsU/7/), it seems that `++` is ok with a variable but not inline.

So, no inline `++` for us in Javascript?

Comment: That's not how `++` works. What's wrong with `+1`?

Comment: Well, no ++ for function calls...

Comment: @32bitkid : nothing wrong, just testing stuff here.

Comment: A cleaner way to do it would be: `$('#TextBox').val(function(){ return parseInt(this.value, 10)+1; });`

Comment: If you want to have some `+` signs together in a confusing way that works, do it like this `1 + + "5"; // 6`

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709866/whats-a-valid-left-hand-side-expression-in-javascript-grammar) You're receiving this error in the console: `Reference Error: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`

Comment: Obviously you failed to research what `++` means. Please tell us, in detail, what you actually expected to happen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I know what it means, I just couldn't see it for some reason, meaning once I got the answer I felt horrible. But I hope this is a good thread for beginners, maybe it'll help some of us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing particular to jQuery about this. `++` increments a variable. You are trying to increment the return value of a function call.

Comment: Yes. ++ is an operator that only applies to variables and properties of objects.

Comment: then why is `parseInt($('#TextBox').val()) + 1` working fine ?

Comment: @Gloserio `++` performs an _assignment_ , where are you changing a property/variable value here? It's for the same reason `1++` doesn't work and `1+1` does. See [the language specification on the Postfix incremenet](http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1) operator.

Comment: @Gloserio — `+` doesn't modify a variable.

Comment: I think the "real" reason is that `+ 1` **produces the value of** one more, `++` **post**-increments (returning current value)

Comment: God ! I'll go kill myself and let you know ... :(

Answer (score 4):

**Q:** What does `x++` mean?

**A:** `x++` means take the value of `x`, let's call this `n`, then set `x` to be `n + 1`, then return `n`.

**Q:** Why does this fail on a non-variable?

**A:** Let's try it on something simple, say `3`, and see where things go wrong.

1. Take the value of `3` and call it `n`, okay, `n = 3`
2. Set `3` to be `n + 1`, so `3 = 3 + 1`, `3 = 4` this makes no sense! So if this step can't be done, the `++` operator can't be used.

Comment: Lols, I can actually even make you even more mad if I tell you I know this :p

Answer (score 0):

`++` works on variables, not directly on numbers

```
var c = parseInt($('#TextBox').val());
$('#TextBox').val( ++c );
```

Change the order from

```
var x = 0;

var result = x++;

result // 0
```

To

```
var x = 0;

var result = ++x;

result // 1
```

Then it will evaluate `++` before retrieving the value.